# Android - Can I call a function of the app in the module?

Tags: android

First : app  called Module's Activity
Second : Module want to Call app's Method

Example:)

- app have [public int sum(int a, int b)] method in com.example.myapplication.calcurate
- module Needs call sum(1,2) and return 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your module to recognize your app (also a module). yo need the add this line in your dependencies (in your module gradle):

```
implementation project(':app')
```

After adding this line your module will be able to use your public class from 'app module'

Or

you can make your `'com.example.myapplication.calcurate'` as [library](https://www.google.com/search?q=aar%20android&rlz=1C1EJFA_enIL982IL982&oq=aar%20android&aqs=chrome..69i57j46i199i433i465i512j0i433i512j0i131i433i512j0i433i512j69i60l3.2672j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and then add the arr file to your module and use it

Comment: I understand that doing so will increase the cohesion. Aren't there any alternatives?

Comment: Sorry..
Not cohesion 
It's Coupling

Comment: I've edit my answer.